# Can't handle exception with try/catch

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, goutte

I'm using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) (which uses [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)) to extract content and my script ends with an error although I'm running in try/catch:

```
Error: Client error: `GET http://example.com/C42C9CA3` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "htt (truncated...)
```

This is what I have:

```
use Goutte\Client;
$HTTPconfig = [ "curl" => [
                  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
                  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                ],
                ['http_errors' => false]
              ];
$HTTPclient = new \Goutte\Client;
$HTTPclient->setClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client($HTTPconfig));
$HTTPclient->setHeader('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:20.0) Gecko/20121202 Firefox/20.0');

try {
  $crawler = $HTTPclient->request('GET', $url);
  $doc = $crawler->html();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  write($e->getMessage());
  continue;
}
```

Comment: So that output isn't coming from `write($e->getMessage());`?

Comment: @JonStirling No, I added try/catch later and it still ends with that error.

Comment: And it's definitely this bit of code that's causing it? I see no reason this would fail and just stop execution.

Comment: Yes exactly, its weird but thats what happening. `http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/itemdetails/06P4069/460/0E80436C80A748E6AA76791FC42C9CA3` is the URL.

Comment: Can't replicate using the provided code and URL.

Comment: @JonStirling really? Using Goutte?

Comment: Yup. Basic composer.json file with goutte, `composer install`, copied your code into a test file, got rid of the write function call, defined `$url` as the URL you provided. No exception thrown, no error and could dump out `$doc` which contained the markup from the forbidden response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
```

instead of:

```
  } catch (Exception $e) {
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using PHP-7 you can try to catch [Throwable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) always with a slash as follow:

```
  } catch (\Throwable $e) {
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes - especially if you've `namespace`'d the file you're working in. (Unclear from your example.)

Comment: Just tried, it still the same! One bad URL can be such a roadblock ah!

Comment: Yes I'm using PHP7. Tried that as well, no luck. :( Can't believe I'm stuck here since a day just because of this. Shouldn't have use Goutte.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `['http_errors' => false]` option. It is `true` by default, and results with exception for 4xx/5xx response codes.

Comment: Tried, still the same. :(